# invariant subspaces of given vector space of odd dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is vector space such that $\dim V $ is odd. Then any linear operator in $V$ has an invariant subspace other than $V$ or $\{ 0 \}$

Why is this true? Can someone help me see this? Maybe for the case when $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ to make things easier to grasp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dimension of $V$ is odd, let me say $\dim V=n$, thus the characteristic polynomial of $f$ has degree $n$, so it has al least one real eigenvalue $\lambda$. The eigenspace associate to $\lambda$ is invariant for $f$.